# How to add typed text in magento 2 using typed.js?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have tried to add on **typed text animation** in my Magento 2 cms page. I am using [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/)

Does anyone have an idea of how to use typed.js in Magento2?

Comment: Hi Bharat , please check my way & let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested but seems not working. in console shows an error. http://prntscr.com/suarmp

Comment: I think you have made some mistake in require-config.js file

Comment: can you share requirejs-config.js file

Comment: var config = {
    'paths': {
        "typejs":'node_modules/typed.js/lib/typed',
    }
};

placed in Magento_Theme folder in the child theme

Comment: kindly please check view-source ...
check html content and js script

Comment: Working fine now. I missed making two folders inside node_modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here is the example to use typed.js*.

create requirejs-config.js inder Magento_Cms module or theme root path like

> ***app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/requirejs-config.js***

```
var config = {
    'paths': {
        "typejs":'node_modules/typed.js/lib/typed',
    }
};
```

That means your's node module location will be ***lib/web/node_modules***

*Next step to add html and script into your cms page.* ***-->*** This is for demo purpose, you should use script into phtml file.

```
<div id="typed-strings">
<p>Typed.js is a <strong>JavaScript</strong> library.</p>
<p>It <em>types</em> out sentences.</p>
</div>
<span id="typed"></span>
<script>// <![CDATA[
    require([
        'typejs',
        'jquery'
    ], function (Typed,$) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var options = {
                     stringsElement: '#typed-strings',
                    typeSpeed: 40
                   }
             var typed = new Typed("#typed", options);
        });
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks :)